# Why $[x:y] \rightarrow [x^3:xy^2:y^3] $ isn't an holomorphic immersion?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Why the following map isn't an holomorphic immersion?

$ F:\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ $[x:y] \rightarrow [x^3:xy^2:y^3] $

I have to check 3 things:

1)It's holomorphic. ok

2)It's injective. ok

3)Locally, for every p $\in$ X, one of the coordinates of $ F(p) \in F(X)$ gives a local chart for $F(X)$.

I think I have to look at $[1:0]$ to show that 3) is not true, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Note that your map is $[1, z]\mapsto [1, z^2, z^3]$, so in a chart its $z\mapsto (z^2, z^3)$.  So you know why it is not immersed?

Comment: @ArcticChar I think I can say that $(z^2,z^3)$ is a cuspidal curve, so it's not an immersed Riemann surface. But how can I say this using local charts? I understand that $z^2$ isn't a local chart, but why $z^3$ isn't either?

Comment: Do you know what is the definition that a function is immersed at a point?

Comment: @ArcticChar The definition of holomorphic immersion that my professor gived is the one that I wrote: 1) 2) 3). And my professor said that the map isn't a holomorphic immersion because $z^2$ and $z^3$ aren't local charts around $0$. I don't understand this point

Comment: So what is a local chart?

Comment: @ArcticChar It's a map $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where U is a open set  of the Riemann surface (so in this case $P^1$) that is a homeomorphism with its image.

Comment: Then it is not so difficult: $z\mapsto z^2$ and $z\mapsto z^3$ are both not injective (when defined in any open neighborhood of $0$)

Comment: @ArcticChar You're right. I was missing something very stupid. Thank you for your help.